# ASP MVC 5 Auto Complete not working

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, typeahead.js

i am pretty new to ASP MVC 5 and after reading several tutorials I still cannot seem to implement a simple autocomplete feature. My issue is that the data that the View is receiving is [Object object] and I have no idea why. The number of fetched words is correct, the only problem is that it does not show "words" just [Object object].

So this is my model:

```
public class Vassal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    public class  VassalDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Vassal> Vassals { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my Controller (VassalControlller)

```
 public JsonResult AutoComplete(string search)
     {
         var vassalNames = from m in db.Vassals
                           select m;

         if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
         {
             vassalNames = vassalNames.Where(s => s.Type.Contains(search));
         }
         return Json(vassalNames, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
     }
```

and this is my View

```html
@model IEnumerable<webVassal.Models.Vassal>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Search";
}

 
<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
    <input id="tags" />
</div>


<script type="text/javascript" >       
    $(function () {
        $('#tags').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '@Url.Action("AutoComplete")',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
                    data: {
                        search: $("#tags").val()
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item
                            };
                        }));
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 1
        });
    });  
</script>
```

I am using Jquery 2.1.1, jquery-ui.min.js and jquery.ui.widget.js

Also if I were to adapt the code above to use the Twitter bootstrap typeahead plugin, what would I need to do? I tried following the instructions on this link http://deanhume.com/home/blogpost/twitter-bootstrap-typeahead-and-asp-net-mvc---key-value-pairs/88 and I was getting a hasOwnProperty error.

I apologize for any format issues i am kind of new on posting code issues.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to replace

```html
return {
    label: item
};
```

with

```html
return {
    label: item.Name
};
```

you are returning an array of Objects not strings, so you will need to access the Name property on each in your success clause.

i think you should ask the bookstrap typeahead question separately.

Comment: Well I feel dumb for not noticing that ... Thank you very much for your time and answer.